# InvokeMember can't find my function

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I've googled around, and couldn't find an answer that worked, I'm writing a program that loads all the modules from a folder, then passes a variable to them, and calls them when needed.

In the DLL i've got some very basic code

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Function Sub getManifest(a As Boolean)
       Return "test"
    End Sub
End Class
```

And in my main program I've got some code too.

```
For Each item In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("modules")
    Await Log(New LogMessage(LogSeverity.Info, "Init", " Loading module at " & item))
    Dim DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(item)
    For Each type As Type In DLL.GetExportedTypes()
        Dim c = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
        Dim moduleManifest As moduleManifest = _
            type.InvokeMember( _
                "getManifest", _
                BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
                Nothing, Nothing, New Object() {})
    Next
Next
```

But I always get a

```
MissingMethodException: Method 'module.Class1.getManifest' cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong `BindingFlags`. Your method is neither `NonPublic` nor `Static` (i.e. `Shared` in VB terms).

Use

```
Dim moduleManifest As moduleManifest = _
    type.InvokeMember(
        "getManifest",
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance, _
        Nothing, c, New Object() { True })
```

Also, one of the arguments must be the object `c` of which you want to call `getManifest` and you must pass a Boolean (either `True` or `False`) in the `args` array for the `a` parameter of `getManifest`.

---

A better method is to let the classes implement an interface. That way you can simply cast the object to this interface and call the method directly (without `InvokeMember`).

The best way to accomplish this, is to have a separate library assembly (DLL) for the contracts (interfaces). Then both, your application and the loaded modules (let's call them add-ins) will have to reference this contracts assembly.

```
Public Interface IAddIn
    Function Sub GetManifest(a As Boolean) As ModuleManifest
End Interface
```

Let your external classes implement this interface. Then you can call this methods like this

```
For Each type As Type In DLL.GetExportedTypes()
    Dim addIn = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type), IAddIn)
    If addIn IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim manifest As ModuleManifest = addIn.GetManifest(True)
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Also, either declare the class `ModuleManifest` in the contracts assembly or declare a `IModuleManifest` interface there as well and let the function return a `IModuleManifest`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting a different error now System.ArgumentException: Must specify binding flags describing the invoke operation required (BindingFlags.InvokeMethod CreateInstance GetField SetField GetProperty SetProperty)

Comment: Ok, I added it. Instead, you can also get a method info and call `Invoke` from there: `Dim method As MethodInfo = type.GetMethod("getManifest", BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.Instance)`   `method.Invoke(c, New Object() { True})`